# Pattern recognition in a collection of binary timecourses

Tags: time-series, pattern-recognition

I have a collection of 12 binary time courses (see the picture attached). By binary, I mean that their value is either 1 or 0. In the image I attached, each time course is a different color, and it is considered a value of 1 when the line is present, and a value of 0 when not present.

I am interested in finding patterns in these time courses, both across multiple time courses and across time. I've searched many different machine learning and pattern recognition topics, but nothing seems to come up that would be applicable to this type of data, particularly because I don't know how long these patterns are, which components they contain, and what the tolerance might be to consider two patterns as similar.

I appreciate any insight into possible methods I could use to approach this problem.

[image]